# como utilizar variables en un Row en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero obtener el valor de $row[] mediante un bucle :

he probado diferentes formas y no funcionan...

Como debería de hacerlo....??

```
$c=7;   

for ($contador = 0; $contador < $c; $contador++) {
      
   $tb=$tb."<td>".$row[$contador]."</td>"

    }
```

Gracias.. Chavales...

Comment: Procura dar un mejor contexto por favor, por ejemplo ¿qué almacena *`$row`*?, dices que no funciona pero no indicas que obtienes al momento, recomiendo leas como aportar un [mcve]

Comment: Para obtener un valor se necesita saber como está estructurado y que valores tienes en tu arreglo. Te sugiero que lo agregues para que te podamos apoyar.

Comment: Solo pretendo saber porqué no me funciona '$row[$variable]'  en php....y el codigo es lo mas sencillo que puedo expresarlo....solo eso...

Comment: Coincido con los amigos de los comentarios anteriores, a tu pregunta le falta algo de cuerpo. Por otro lado, ¿estas seguro de que `$row[]` es un **Array numérico indexado** y no un **Array asociativo**?

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($row);` y por qué esa forma tan extraña de leer un array? ¿Por qué no escribir simplemente: `foreach ($row as $k=>$v) { //imprimir cada elemento $k y/o $v }`?